# stack elements in a <td> vertically (fixed size)

Tags: html

my **td** has a fixed size of 30x 30 px in a table of

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed;width:810px">
```

In the td element 2 number should be stacked vertically (2 chars each) with no td resize (like 12 px size letter)  The below applied resizes the height of **br** . How to fix the size to stay @ 30 px? Thanks!

```html
<td id="pos" class="text-sm-center"style="width: 30px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse: collapse">
    <label style="font-size:10px;padding:0px;margin:0px !important">12</label>
    <br style="display: block;content: none;margin: 0px !important">
    <label style="font-size:10px;padding:0px;margin:0px !important">10</label></td>
```

Further notes: bootstrap applied css, br adds significant amount to the table cell height

Comment: further notes: bootstrap applied css, br adds significant amount to the table cell height

Answer (score 0):

OK so ended up with explicit line height on 'p' element (razor syntax)

[image]

```
 <td id="pos" @onmousedown="@((e) => OnMouseDown(e, pos))" @onmouseover="@((e) => OnMouseOver(e, pos))" @onmouseup="OnMouseUp"
            class="text-sm-center" style="background-color: @plate.DctWellInfoByPosition[pos].ColorCode; width: 30px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse: collapse">
            <p style="margin:0px;padding:0px;line-height:0.7"><label style="font-size:10px;margin:0px;padding:0px;">123</label></p>
            <p style="margin: 0px;padding: 0px;line-height: 0.7"><label style="font-size:10px;margin:0px;padding:0px;color:blue">321</label></p> 
        </td>
```